# Auto Check Availability Position in PHP - MLM Project

Tags: php

My intention to make possible is this

If i am the USER my LEFT and RIGHT are like "L" and "R"

i want php should automatically chk the possible empty place to register. like

1=L, 2=R, 3=LL, 4=RL, 5=LR, 6=RR

```
       user
       / \
  (1) L   R (2)
     /\   /\
(3) LL LR RL RR (6)
      (5) (4)
```

if it founds "RL" position is empty (new user should register under "RL")

my database is having ID, Username, Child_L, Child_R

**Here i have written this code below**

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';
$username = "kishore";
$log=mysql_query("select * from users where username='".$username."'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($log);

$child_left=$row['child_l'];
$child_left=$row['child_r'];

function chkchild($childuser){
    $log=mysql_query("select * from users where username='".$childuser."'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($log);

    $child_left=$row['child_l'];
    $child_left=$row['child_r'];

    if ($child_left = NULL) {

        echo"you can register under child_l";
    }elseif ($child_right = NULL){
        echo"you can register under child_r";
    }

}


if ($child_left = NULL) {

    echo"you can register under child_l";
}elseif ($child_right = NULL){
    echo"you can register under child_r";
}else 
    chkchild($child_left);


?>
```

**Here is my database table**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYvTH.jpg

Comment: Yes, please give more details.

Comment: Is there anyone to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

might be this will help you

```
function chkchild(){
    while($t)
    {
        $qu=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE child_L='' or child_R='';");
        $rows=mysql_fetch_row($qu);
        if($rows>0)
        {
            echo "No Positions are blank"
        }
        else
        {
            $rs=mysql_fetch_array($qu);
            //Here you can check the complete list of all blank positions
        }
    }
}
```